# Snowflake Net Connector Connection string is invalid

Tags: c#, .net, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to connect to our Snowflake DB using SSO with the ff connection string but keeps on getting an error. I'm using https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-net for my .NET 4.6.1 console application just to test things out. I have confirmed that my SSO is able to login to the Snowflake Web UI. Found related docs: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-security-fed-auth-use.html#native-sso-okta-only

connection string:

`AUTHENTICATOR=https://{okta_account_name}.okta.com;ACCOUNT={org}.{region};HOST={org}.{region}.snowflakecomputing.com;PORT=443;ROLE={role};WAREHOUSE={warehouse};USER={sso email};password={sso password};DB={db};SCHEMA={schema}`

error:

`Exception: Error: Connection string is invalid: Unable to connect SqlState: 08006, VendorCode: 270008, QueryId:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I posted a question too soon. Following the Readme.md for Snowflake Dotnet Connector, I was able to generate the logs thru log4net. The underlying exception was

```
[2021-08-11 23:09:04,732] [1] [ERROR] [Snowflake.Data.Core.SFSession] Unable to connect
System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform.
   at Snowflake.Data.Core.HttpUtil.setupCustomHttpHandler(HttpClientConfig config)
   at Snowflake.Data.Core.HttpUtil.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.<RegisterNewHttpClientIfNecessary>b__1()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.HttpClientBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler>b__1(HttpMessageHandlerBuilder b)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.DefaultHttpClientFactory.<>c__DisplayClass17_0.<CreateHandlerEntry>g__Configure|0(HttpMessageHandlerBuilder b)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.LoggingHttpMessageHandlerBuilderFilter.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<Configure>b__0(HttpMessageHandlerBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.DefaultHttpClientFactory.CreateHandlerEntry(String name)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.DefaultHttpClientFactory.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<.ctor>b__1()
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.DefaultHttpClientFactory.CreateHandler(String name)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.DefaultHttpClientFactory.CreateClient(String name)
   at Snowflake.Data.Core.HttpUtil.GetHttpClient(HttpClientConfig config)
   at Snowflake.Data.Core.SFSession..ctor(String connectionString, SecureString password)
```

After browsing the web with similar exception it was mostly about the target .NET framework not satisfying the requirement. I was initially targeting .NET Framework 4.6.1 but after changing it to 4.7.2 everything worked fine as expected. It was indeed mentioned on the repo that the driver is now targeting 4.7.2 but I don't recall seeing it being unable to support lower framework versions. I tried downgrading the driver to the earliest version and upgrading it to the latest one by one with no avail. Hope this help others facing the same issue.

Comment: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/release-notes/requirements.html#client-versions-support-policy

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience with `Snowflake.Data`, it  supports .Net framework starting from version 4.6.1.

The connection string is like:

```html
connStr="scheme=https;account=youraccount;host=xxx.snowflakecomputing.com;port=443;proxyhost=xx.myproxy.com;proxyport=80;role=MY_ROLE;warehouse=WAREHOUSE_NAME;user=userid;password=xxx;authenticator=xxx.okta.com"
```

You may also try to set `authenticator=externalbrowser`.

I personally prefer to connect to Snowflake using ODBC Driver. Please refer to https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/odbc.html on how to install ODBC driver in your local machine. Once you install and configure Snowflake in your machine, you may connect to Snowflake using `System.Data.Odbc`library.

The connection string might looks like:

```html
connStr="Dsn=DataSourceName;uid=userID;pwd=xxx"
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also try browser-based SSO:

In the connection string, set AUTHENTICATOR=externalbrowser, and set USER to the login name for your IdP.

using (IDbConnection conn = new SnowflakeDbConnection())
{
conn.ConnectionString = "account=testaccount;authenticator=externalbrowser;user={login_name_for_IdP};db=testdb;schema=testschema";

```
conn.Open();

conn.Close();
```

}
where:

{login_name_for_IdP} is your login name for your IdP.